# How to push notification with difference content within activate app?

Tags: android, refresh, push-notification

I had implement this [push notification](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html).

I tried with push first message, it work. After that i change the message and push again, but the content cannot reach into the app. it was still receive first message. For example, first message is "ABC". second message is "DEF", when i click the notification into the app, then the message still show "ABC" instead of "DEF". if i manually run the app, after that i push message "DEF", it does receive "DEF".

How to make the app always accept the latest message when user click the notification directly jump into app instead of running the apps manually from beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add the flag [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) to you notification [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) to replace the extra from the existing Pending intent to the new one.

There is also the flag [FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) if you want to delete the old PendingIntent and replace it by the new one.

Comment: got anyway to dismiss the notification after click. 
**note that, after click, app will not start because i set intent = null

Answer (score 0):

just pass in an empty intent like intent()   and use this flag in your notification flag settings:   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;